# R function to display internet/network activity

Tags: r

I'm trying to download a file, but the function I'm using has no status messages, so I can't tell if it's working or just hanging.

What is the R function that displays the current internet/network activity messages?

Comment: Using `dowload.file` like this `download.file('https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/R-3.3.1-win.exe', '/tmp/bla.exe')` gives me a progressbar. Which function are you using? In addition, which OS are you using. This will greatly influence what the solution is, as a network activity indicator will probably involve some system commands.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using custom packages. I know the function I'm describing exists, as I've used it before, but I can't seem to find it using Google or SO searches.

Comment: You could simply monitor the network traffic using the tools your OS provides. Linux has a fair bunch, Windows should also have tool that can show you network activity.

Comment: I found `options(internet.info = 0)` which seems to be part of the solution